# Trying to read confusion matrices

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

[image]

I am given these 2 confusion matrix for a homework assignment but I am unsure how to interpret the data. I am asked to make a decision with these two matrices. For the first matrix am I interpreting this right:

-We predict that 4 are yes but really there are 5

-We predict 1 No but there are 90??

I am just very confused with this confusion matrix (ha)

Answer (score 1):

For the first table $$\begin{array}{|c|cc|} \hline & p & n \\\hline y & 4 & 5 \\ n & 1 & 90\\ \hline\end{array} $$

We predicted $9$ of them to be yes (look at the sum over first row) but really there are only $4$ (top left entry).

We predicted $91$ of them to be no (look at the sum over second row) but really there are $90$ (bottom right entry). Most entries that we predict to be negative are indeed negative.